# is it possible to organize the display of all the notifications on the smartphone using a button without leaving the application?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

first of all I want to apologize for the lack of code, since I have never come across this at all, and I almost did not find material on this topic ... I use C # + Unity 2020, and I had the task of reproducing all notifications that are on the phone by clicking on a button in the application - it should look something like this: you press the button, and you are shown all the notifications that are on the smartphone (while you are still in the application), you can look at them and then do something else .. ...

Please, who knows, I will be very grateful: is this even possible? and how best to organize it? If it's not difficult, you would help me a lot ...

Comment: You really need to provide more detail. This is not a workable question as written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are looking at an OS-specific feature you would have to write your own native plugin(s) to get the notification data.

See: [Building and using plug-ins for Android](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html)  /  [Building plug-ins for iOS](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)

At least on Android the feature to get the Notification information does exist, I'm not sure about iOS:
[NotificationListenerService.getActiveNotifications()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService#getActiveNotifications())

Comment: Wow, thanks, I didn't think that someone would answer, this question has such a low score ... One more question: this method ... is it accompanied by something? Well, am I in the sense that I can simply use this method to display all the notifications that I have on the phone screen? Or does it somehow look different? Thanks again:)